# BigQuery API on gcp compute instance

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, instance

New to BigQuery on GCP
I'm trying to query tables on a public dataset on gcp.
I'd like to query the tables via my compute instance (debian).
Is there a step by step out there?

Thanks
MS

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bq

Answer (score 0):

Please find step below.

1. Create your Compute Engine with Custom scope and Enable Bigquery access.
   If you already created instance , stop the instance and then click on edit it will allow you to change the service account scope.

[image]

2. now run your query with bq as below.

bq query --nouse_legacy_sql 
'SELECT
*
FROM
`bigquery-public-data`.samples.shakespeare limit 2'

[image]